# why does alert(json[0].subject); give undefined?

Tags: jquery, json

i have this code:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        refresh();
    });

    function refresh()
    {      
        $.get('getMessageDetails.php', function (json) {
            alert(json);
            alert(json[0].subject);
        },"json");
        window.setTimeout(refresh,30000);
    }   
</script>
```

then i have getMessageDetails.php:

```
<?php
//header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
include('header_application.php');
$lastNewMessageCnt = $obj_clean->getUnopenedMessagesCount($_SESSION['user_id']) + 1;
$last_unopened_message_row = $obj_clean->getLastUnopenedMessage($_SESSION['user_id'],$lastNewMessageCnt); 
echo json_encode($last_unopened_message_row); 
?>
```

then i have the alert(json) which shows:

```
[{"subject":"Freechat ddd","id":"19","created_at":"2011-08-29 14:58:27","unique_code":"ALLEYCA000RC","opened_once":"0"}]
```

which is correct

but `alert(json[0].subject);` gives undefined???

please help?
thank you

Comment: Why aren't you using $.getJSON(): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ ?

Comment: i am way to new to all this and have no clue on how to do that. read through the link you gave me but waaaay to complicated...wouldnt know where to start to change all my code to incorporate using getJSON. the file im calling is a .php because i need to get values from a database table...FYI: this site is a MOBILE site though

Comment: But it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/majidf/CM7Tm/

Comment: yikes then i dont know...why am i getting undefined then? im so frustrated....

Comment: If you are able to use $.get it shouldn't be too tough to progress to $.getJSON (actually it's easier as it automatically handles the JSON for you!!!). See the examples on the jQuery-doc and how they process the data that gets returned from the call. The cat example helped me a lot a while ago....

Comment: i know about the cat example but how will i code my .json file?? my values are not hard coded..yikes this stuff confuses me :(

Comment: In this case I always use Firebug's method: console.dir(object); Which produces all the properties and methods. Instead of: alert(json); Use: console.dir(json) It will definetely provide much more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your first alert shows what you say it does, then the content of your `json` variable is not being treated as json - if it was you'd see `[object Object]` in the alert. Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/majidf/CM7Tm/#base).

So you need to specify what is returned is json (which you do); but you should also make sure PHP is sending the correct response headers. Add the first line below, before you send output:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($last_unopened_message_row);
```

Comment: i copied and pasted what was in the alert.. i commented out the header line just to check...i have put it back in alert now gives []???

Comment: So, I am wrong - even the correct headers could not force correct type casting. In that case follow what @Rocket is suggesting, or at least do as Pavan Agarwal says.

Comment: It looks as though when you try to send the correct (json) header, no output is sent at all. This could be a combination of error reporting being off and a fatal error happening somewhere. So, either investigate what causes the `white screen of death`, or as a (bad) workaround forget about sending the correct header and just send the output as text - client side however, parse the json with `json = $.parseJSON(json);` as @Pavan Agarwal suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert json variable to correct json format variable.

Currently its a string variable.

You have to use it following way :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        refresh();
    });

    function refresh()
    {      
        $.get('getMessageDetails.php', function (json) {
            alert(json);  // this is a string variable.
            json = $.parseJSON(json);  //now json varible is in correct json format.
            alert(json.subject); //you can call it dirctly like a associative array. No need to include '[0]'.
        },"json");
        window.setTimeout(refresh,30000);
    }   
</script>
```

Comment: If you're gonna use `parseJSON`, you don't need the `,"json"` at the end of `get`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your JSON is not getting parsed correctly.  Try using `getJSON` instead.

```
$.getJSON('getMessageDetails.php', function (json) {
   alert(json);
   alert(json[0].subject);
});
```

Comment: alert shows nothing :) in firebug the response tab just show []